# How to increase 1 number value for a Hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

`@participants[id]={nick: nick, points: 0}` => {"1"=>{:nick=>"Test", :points=>0}

I want to add in points for ID `1`. I did `@participants["1"].points+=1` but it does not work. How do I make it to add 1 each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@participants["1"]` is also an hash, so

```
@participants["1"][:points] += 1
```